# How to study the effect of 2 drugs (used singly and in combination) compared to a placebo on a disease

Tags: multiple-comparisons, crossover-study, therapy

I want to study the effect of 2 drugs (used singly and in combination) compared to a placebo on a disease. What is the best statistical method? Kindly provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to compare is to see if the mean outcome is improved or not by using the mean. You dont want to do this with ordinary t-tests as the tests are not independent and the probabilities would no longer be accurate (you would have a larger type 1 error).

Therefore you want to test the means jointly using for example an ANOVA test that does not suffer from the inflated type 1 error.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide any additional special steps to be taken using t ANOVA?

Comment: The procedure is a little tedious but here is a good explanation of how to do it step by step in great detail:

http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_HypothesisTesting-ANOVA/BS704_HypothesisTesting-Anova_print.html

Almost all statistical software will do this automatically for you in a built in function. I hope this helps but if not I am sure someone else can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have statistical software. The reference is quite useful.